# ExtJS 6.2.1 - How to change the UI of Ext.toast()?

Tags: javascript, css, toast, extjs6-classic, extjs6.2

Hi all and thank you for your time!

I was wondering how one could to change the UI of the ExtJS 6.2.1 Ext.toast()...

For example I would like to have toasts with a red(ish) border to inform the user when a error occurs, and green(ish) when an operation was successfuly completed, and the normal theme color for all other notifications, for example...

Could you please guide me to the correct code on how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Tested on ExtJS 7. I Guess it works on 6 as well.

Create an override scss file:

```
/packages/local/yourtheme/sass/src/window/Toast.scss
```

Inside:

```
$toast-red-color: #ffe0db;
$toast-yellow-color: #fff8d2;
$toast-green-color: #efffd2;
$toast-font-weight: 600;

// Red
@include extjs-window-ui(
    $ui: 'red-toast',
    $ui-header-background-color: $toast-red-color,
    $ui-border-color: $toast-red-color,
    $ui-header-border-color: $toast-red-color,
    $ui-body-border-color: $toast-red-color,
    $ui-body-background-color: $toast-red-color,
    $ui-body-font-weight: $toast-font-weight,
    $ui-border-width: 5px,
    $ui-border-radius: 5px,
    $ui-header-color: $toast-red-color
);

// Green
@include extjs-window-ui(
    $ui: 'green-toast',
    $ui-header-background-color: $toast-green-color,
    $ui-border-color: $toast-green-color,
    $ui-header-border-color: $toast-green-color,
    $ui-body-border-color: $toast-green-color,
    $ui-body-background-color: $toast-green-color,
    $ui-body-font-weight: $toast-font-weight,
    $ui-border-width: 5px,
    $ui-border-radius: 5px,
    $ui-header-color: $toast-green-color
);

// Yellow
@include extjs-window-ui(
    $ui: 'yellow-toast',
    $ui-header-background-color: $toast-yellow-color,
    $ui-border-color: $toast-yellow-color,
    $ui-header-border-color: $toast-yellow-color,
    $ui-body-border-color: $toast-yellow-color,
    $ui-body-background-color: $toast-yellow-color,
    $ui-body-font-weight: $toast-font-weight,
    $ui-border-width: 5px,
    $ui-border-radius: 5px,
    $ui-header-color: $toast-yellow-color
);

/* Global changes */
.#{$prefix}toast {
    @include box-shadow(rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 0 0px 0px);

    .x-window-body-default {
         // More specific changes, if needed
    }

    .x-autocontainer-outerCt {
        // More specific changes, if needed
    }
}
```

In this case, you'll have 3 ui's that you can use like this:

```
Ext.toast({
    html: 'This is an example',
    title: null,
    align: 't',
    ui: 'yellow-toast'
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Can confirm, this works on 7.3.0 Classic

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.Toast` resp. `Ext.toast` is basically an Ext.Panel. My first approach was to try and create a ui with the `panel-ui` mixin. Apparently, this did not work. A working solution instead is to create a Toast instance with a base CSS class, e.g. like this:

```
var t = Ext.create('Ext.Toast',{cls: 'mytoast',timeout: 2000});
t.show({message: 'foo'});
```

Then, define the `.mytoast` css class, e.g. in `sass/etc/all.scss`:

```
.mytoast {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

This seems to work, even if it feels a bit "off the Ext way".

Comment: Thanks for you input! I changed from Toast() to toast just to make it right! I will try your suggestion, and i will give you an input has soon has i can!

Comment: I have tried it, but with no luck! If i place the code on sass/etc/all.scss the error [ERR] Can't find variable: extjs_panel_ui__mix is thrown... If i move the file to sass/src/Application.scss it has no efect on the toast (or any other panel...)

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry, wrong file: put it in `sass/var/all.scss`. I edited the code above.

Comment: Hi, sory for the late reply. It still does not work! i placed the code in sass/var/all.scss and even tried in classic/sass/var/all.scss and the exception [ERR] Can't find variable: extjs_panel_ui__mix is still thrown! Could you please provide a simple fiddle? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, indeed this does not seem to work at all, sorry for that. See my 2nd approach above, I edited the original answer. This example worked in my setup.

Comment: This solution only applies the class to the header div.
`<div class="x-title mytoast x-window-header-title x-window-header-title-default x-box-item x-title-default x-title-rotate-none x-title-align-left" role="presentation" unselectable="on" id="toast-1168_header-title" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 328px;"><div id="toast-1168_header-title-textEl" data-ref="textEl" class="x-title-text x-title-text-default x-title-item" unselectable="on" role="presentation">&nbsp;</div></div>`